# Redcarpet, render html with links inside <span> and not <p>

Tags: ruby, redcarpet

I'm using the [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) gem to render html from markdown.

The following markdown

```
(link)[example.com]
```

renders this html

```
<p>
    <a href="example.com">link</a>
</p>
```

How can I make it render html like this

```
<span>
    <a href="example.com">link</a>
</span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Redcarpet isn't wrapping your link in a `<p>`, it's wrapping the paragraph. It just so happens that the paragraph consists of nothing but a link. I realize that doesn't help you solve your problem *per se*, but hopefully it helps you understand what's going on. Here's a related GitHub issue: https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/issues/92

Comment: Thanks a lot! Used this line `full_document.gsub /<p><a(.*)>(.*)<\/a><\/p>/i, '<a\1>\2</a>'` to get whatever I wanted